# Apache 2.4, www.domain.de working but not domain.de

Tags: domains, redirects, apache

I just moved to a new Host with my website and reinstalled the web server (this time apache 2.4)
I'm not very used to the virtual hosts, but I managed to get my subdomain forum.domain.de running (working directory /var/www/html/forum.domain.de
Now what I wanted was that if someone trys to go on domain.de that he will be redirected to the forum.domain.de

for that I created a simple index.php in /var/www/html with a 301 redirect to the forum.domain.de

when I now try to connect www.domain.de it will redirect me to the forum, but if I try to connect to domain.de (without "www." all I get is a connection timed out...

Comment: Show us how you did your redirect

Comment: "Connection timeout" tells me it isn't even getting to Apache.   You have a DNS problem.

Comment: @JohnConde  `<?php header('Location: http://forum.domain.de/index.php');`

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes that sounds most likely since it also works when i just enter the correct IP of my host, the domain was transfere from the old host but just some hours ago, propably - if its a DNS problem I guess I will just have to wait?

Comment: Your Apex record is not correct, not set, or not propogated.

Comment: alright, I checked my browsers DNS cache and I can see that "domain.de" still points on the old's host IP address even after clearing that cache.... strange thing that it works to connect to "forum.domain.de" then? because that one is already pointing to the correct new IP. should I contact the hosting company or just wait?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED:

The problem was indeed a DNS problem BUT not on DNS-side 
when I checked the A record it pointed to the correct IP address, but the wrong IP address is cached somewhere on my local computer

ANSWER:

so how did I solve the problem was to flush the DNS caches:

1. I was using Chrome Browser, flushing DNS cache like answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/203702) and then flushing the socket pools like in the [next answer](https://superuser.com/a/611712)
2. flushing the Windows DNS cache like explained [here](http://www.tippscout.de/windows-dns-cache-loeschen_tipp_2292.html)